# Justificable to round non-integer values to use Poisson/Negative Binomial Regression?

Tags: r, mixed-model, count-data, lognormal-distribution, poisson-regression

I have mean litter size values reported from a number of studies.  They are count data, but because I'm using the averages, they aren't integers (although they are the means of count data).  It seems like a Poisson or Negative Binomial GLMM using the study site as a random intercept would the most appropriate choice for modeling effects of a number of environmental predictors on the response of litter size.

Is it justifiable to round my average litter size values to that I can have integers to use?  Would it be better to log-transform these values?  What considerations should I take into account?

Comment: Could you back those mean values into *total* values?  (All you need to know is the count of litters.)  That would give you something valid to work with.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The values were taken from a meta-analysis across many studies so we don't have access to the raw data, and the count of litters are usually not reported in the articles.

Comment: Here's the problem: study (A), in which environmental factor "X" is absent, reports a mean litter size of 3.5.  Study (B), in which "X" is present at a constant level, but otherwise everything was identical to study (A), reports a mean size of 2.5.  Is the change significant?  It seems to be.  But suppose study (A) involved only eight litters.  How significant does the change look now?  (Answer: regardless of the size of study B, it cannot be significant at the $5\%$ level.) That's why the counts are essential for any valid analysis--you cannot get by without them (or equivalent information).

Comment: We used the coordinates from each study to calculate our own values of the environmental covariates, so none are missing from studies.  We do have estimates of uncertainty for litter size from a subset of studies that reported it.  While I agree it's less than ideal, I'd like to use the data available in the way that makes the most sense statistically.

Comment: Note that even if the serious problem whuber raised were absent, if a Poisson was a good model for the original counts, it *cannot* be a good model for rounded averages; the mean-variance relationship is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments of `whuber`. It's pretty hard to make an estimate of the uncertainty if all you have is averages. Let's say one study has only measured two, and another one has measured a hundred litter bins. Any reasonable analysis would take the uncertainty of those measurements into account and not take the first one too seriously. If you don't know anything about where these averages come from, it's pretty hard to interpret them anyway. This is I think a much bigger issue than the rounding off, if you really want to model this as a distribution. If it looks like a Poisson shape to you, and that's why you use this, perhaps a gamma distribution or lognormal distribution is a better choice.

One principled way to make it work is to put some priors on the number of litter bins measured in each of the studies. You could implement such a thing in a probabilistic programming environment like `stan` or `pymc`. However, I think the answers are going to be very sensitive to your priors on these averages.

As it is, these averages just don't convey much information at all if you don't know how many measurements are done. Would you trust your study if all of them had actually only two measurements? What if one of them has a really large survey size but you base your regression lines on other, far less certain averages?

**Answer to comment below**

> What is the best way to model a response of non-negative non-integer values that are representative of count data?

In theory, if you average five poisson variables, so five pure count-data variables, then the outcome is distributed as a Poisson distributed by 5. The sum of Poisson variables is again Poisson distributed, and the average is the sum divided by five. But you don't know the number of Poissons added together, so that doesn't really work. I don't really know anything about this domain, I don't know if the underlying variables are modelled well as Poisson variables, or something else.

**Other comment**

> Do you have advice between gamma and lognormal

Same answer actually (sorry can't help without more knowledge / information), I think that's where you need information on the process that created these numbers, and how you want to model it. What are litter size values? Why do you think these are best modelled as a Poisson?

Comment: We have estimates of uncertainty for the means in about half the studies.  Unfortunately, ecology is a messy field, and meta-analyses can compound that.  By attempting to compile all global records, we're trying to compensate for the individual studies' lack of rigor with as large of a sample of studies as possible.  I don't think this answer really addresses the question so I'll restate it: What is the best way to model a response of non-negative non-integer values that are representative of count data?

Comment: The averages do convey information because they serve as a flawed representation of the ecological process, just as an estimate with uncertainty quantified is still a flawed representation of the ecological process.  We could subset to the estimates with variance, but they don't all document the variation in the same fashion.  Do you have any advice between a Gamma or lognormal?  I've seen evidence towards not transforming (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00021.x/epdf)

Comment: thanks for the additional comments.  I have both the number of litters and variance of the mean for about half of the 160 values.  One option is to just subset to these values that have uncertainty quantified.  I've never used stan or pymc, and was hoping to keep this analysis in a clear and easy to interpret format like using lme4 in r.  I thought that Poisson might be correct because these are count data (although not in raw form).  I checked the mean and variance when they were rounded versus not rounded, and in both cases the variance of the residuals was much greater than the mean.

Comment: No problem, interesting problem to think about. But there are a couple of different variances that you could have, and I'm not clear on which one you do have. There is the mean of the observations. There is also the residuals, and the mean squared of the residuals, let's say the variance in the data. There is also "variance" in the estimate of the mean, perhaps expressed in a confidence interval or standard error. These are all interesting. There are probably easier ways to implement this analysis than using Stan if you don't know Stan, but I don't know them.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I checked the mean and variance of the residuals of the fitted models.

Comment: Hmm.. I think that that doesn't tell you anything about the uncertainty in the estimated mean. Because, if you have two observations [1, 3], with variance 1, and you have observations [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3], that also has variance 1 (I'm using the biased version here), but in the second case you would be much more sure of the estimated mean, you have more information to go by.

Comment: Right, I agree that doesn't tell anything about the uncertainty in the observations.  My goal was to see if the residuals of the model followed a Poisson distribution or not, so I checked to see if the mean and variance of the residuals were similar.